# Is there a sublime package to highlight unused modules for Python

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I have my Python code in Sublime Text 3, and I want to know if there is a package to highlighting importing-line-code if I am not using a certain module (like Pycharm does). For example:

```
import math
import numpy as np  # this has to be highlighted cause 
                    # I'm not using numpy, just math
print(math.pi)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SublimeLinter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/stable/) with [pycodestyle](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-pycodestyle) or [SublimePythonIDE](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimePythonIDE). They both have a built-in linter.